# AWS Amplify - Accessing the private S3 file from lambda returns access denied

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I created file storage to enable users to privately upload files, which works fine

```
const result = await Storage.put("test.txt", "Private Content", {
  level: "private",
  contentType: "text/plain",
});
```

How can I configure some other AWS resource (lambda trigger or ec2) to access that file for further processing with Amplify? If I try to access it with lambda trigger I get access denied.

Comment: setup s3 notification and set target to lambda whenever user uploads file to s3 lambda will be triggered